# Git add Unity SmartMerge config for both mac and windows

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I want to integrate Unity SmartMerge in my Unity project. For this you need to add the following to the git config:

```
[merge]
tool = unityyamlmerge

[mergetool "unityyamlmerge"]
trustExitCode = false
cmd = '<path to UnityYAMLMerge>' merge -p "$BASE" "$REMOTE" "$LOCAL" "$MERGED"
```

The path `<path to UnityYAMLMerge>` needs to be replaced with the location of the UnityYAMLMerge. On Mac it would be `Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Tools/UnityYAMLMerge`
and on Windows, it would be `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\UnityYAMLMerge.exe`.

---

My Question is if it is possible to add both to the git config? Is there a way, that this runs on both Windows and Mac?